# How to get the predicted probability for one class in random forest multi-class?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

There are 6 classes. I collected 6 CSVs which all include coordinates. After merging them into one, I trained the random forest algorithm to predict the class and it worked fine. Now I need to find the probability for that one class I predicted.

```py
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=60, criterion="entropy", class_weight="balanced")  
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)  

y_pred = classifier.predict(x_test) 

classifier.predict([[0.30815389752388, 0.15675216913223267, 0.30418527126312256, 0.13528722524642944, 0.27739858627319336, 0.13911670446395874, 0.1855921745300293, 0.2289518266916275, 0.3659476339817047, 0.20354066789150238, 0.33502599596977234, 0.24855738878250122, 0.4515098035335541, 0.258819043636322, 0.5094516277313232, 0.2201528549194336, 0.5327972173690796, 0.24092578887939453, 0.2740940749645233, 0.47397956252098083, 0.3831675946712494, 0.46537867188453674, 0.24977758526802063, 0.6157410144805908, 0.3534936010837555, 0.4986037611961365, 0.3416776955127716, 0.882462739944458, 0.2505697011947632, 0.7096155881881714]])
```

Comment: You can use `classifier.predict_proba(x_test)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `y_proba = classifier.predict_proba(x_test)`.

This will return an array with six columns because you have 6 classes. The order of the columns will be the same as `classifier.classes_`.

Check out the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba) for more details.